# find the maximum value associated with same key in map in c++

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap

suppose a map contains elements like {(a,2),(b,3),(a,24),(c,8),(b,55)} . I have to find the maximum value associated with same key. Here for a the maximum value is 24, for b maximum value is 55, for c maximum value is 8. How to do this in C++? please help

Comment: multimap, you mean?

Comment: actually I could not find the maximum value of the same key. I don't know about multimap much. can you please help me how to find the maximum value of the same key using multimap

Comment: is hashing needed here?

Comment: You must mean multimap. You can use `equal_range` to get an iterator pair for all entries for a given key. Then you can use `std::max_element(range.first, range.second, [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.second < b.second; })` to get the maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

If your map contains data like you mentioned, then it must be a `multimap`, because it contains duplicate keys. A "normal" `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` has unique keys. So, they cannot contain 2 same characters 'a' as a key.

We can solve your problem with the build in [functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) of the `std::multimap`.

We will first iterate over all keys and get back a range of where there are. For this we can use the `std::multimap`s [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/upper_bound) `upper_bound`, to iterate over the same keys. Then we will use the function [equal_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range), to get a range for all entries having the same key.

Then we use the function `std::max_element` from the algorithm library, to get the [max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) value, using the range obtained by the `equal_range` function.

This could then look like for example the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    // Define the multimap
    std::multimap<char, int> data{ {'a',2},{'b',3},{'a',24},{'c',8},{'b',55}};

    // Iterate over the keys in the multimap
    for (auto it{ data.begin() }; it != data.end(); it = data.upper_bound(it->first)) {

        // Get the range of all data with the same key
        const auto& [start, end] = data.equal_range(it->first);

        // Get max element and show result
        std::cout << "Key: " << it->first << "\tMax: " << std::max_element(start, end, [](const auto i1, const auto i2) {return i1.second < i2.second; })->second << '\n';
    }
}
```